# Change color of X axis values to multi color values - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) for charting.
My type Chart is Bar.

Label of X axis have 4 lines.
I Change color of X axis values. color of values is one color.
But I want one line per color and color same like the bar color.

```
var barChartData = {
    labels: [["Injection", 10, 20], // here I want to change the color
        ["Electronics", 5, 15],
        ["TOTAL", 15, 35]
    ],
    datasets: [{
        label: "2018",
        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.orange,
        yAxisID: 'A',
        data: [10, 5, 15]
    }, {
        label: "2017",
        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,
        yAxisID: 'A',
        data: [20, 15, 35]
    }]
 };

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
new Chart(canvas, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                id: 'A',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'left',
            }, {
                id: 'B',
                type: 'linear',
                position: 'right',
                ticks: {
                    max: 100,
                    min: 0
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    fontColor: "#222", // This here that I changed.
                },
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

I want to change color of labels are 10, 5, 15 is orange and 20, 15, 35 is green and Injection, Electronics, TOTAL is black

Can I do that? How?

Answer (score 1):

```
var myData = [
  ["id1","test 11111","AA",1.95],
  ["id2","test 2","BB",1.94],
  ["id3","test 3","CC",1.93],
  ["id4","test 4","DD",1.93],
  ["id5","test 5","EE",1.91],
  ["id6","test 6","FF",1.90],
  ["id7","test 7","GG",1.82],
  ["id8","test 8","HH",1.85],
  ["id9","test 9","II",1.83],
  ["id10","test 10","JJ",1.79]
];


var ctx = $("#c");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      xAxisID:'modelAxis',
      data: myData.map((entry)=>entry[3])
    }]
  },
  options:{
    scales:{
      xAxes:[
        {
          id:'modelAxis',
          type:"category",
          ticks:{
            //maxRotation:0,
            autoSkip: false,
            callback:function(label, x2, x3, x4){
              return label;
            }
                   },
         labels:myData.map((entry=>entry[1]))
        },
        {
          id:'groupAxis',
          type:"category",
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
            drawBorder: false,
            drawOnChartArea: false,
            offsetGridLines: false
          },
          ticks:{
            padding:0,
            maxRotation:0,
            fontSize: 10,
            fontColor: '#FF9090',
            autoSkip: false,
            callback:function(label){
                return label;
            }
          },
          offset: true,
          labels:myData.map((entry=>entry[1]))

        },{
          id:'groupAxis2',
          type:"category",
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
            drawBorder: false,
            drawOnChartArea: false,
            offsetGridLines: false
          },
          scaleLabel:{ 
            padding: 10,
          },
          ticks:{
            padding:0,
            fontSize: 10,
            fontColor: '#AB64F4',
            maxRotation:0,
            autoSkip: false,
            callback:function(label){
                return label;
            }
          },
          offset: true,
          labels:myData.map((entry=>entry[1]))

        }
        ],
      yAxes:[{
        ticks:{
          beginAtZero:true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```